# Rails 5 add custom action to REST route with :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, cancan

In my Rails 5 app I have a route for a REST controller:

```
resources :payments
```

I want to add a new action pay to the resource, so I put:

```
resources :payments do
   get 'pay'
end
```

Where as my original routes look for example like this:

```
/payments/:id/edit
```

The custom route uses :payment_id instead of :id

```
/payments/:payment_id/pay
```

How can I change the route to:

```
payments/:id/pay
```

?

I need this because CanCanCan automatically sets the payment in the controller but looks for :id and not for :payment_id

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
resources :payments do
  get 'pay', on: :member
end
```

as described [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions).